# how to make this image hover effect like the airforce website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, hover

I keep trying but in vain
I have 5 images side by side and want to make a hover width effect like the airforce website in section two...here is the website: https://www.airforce.com/
scroll down and you will see 5 images side by side and when you hover on an image the width expand without effecting the image itself..I keep trying but the image get effected always..I tried putting each image on bootstrap container and make the width effect on the container itself but the images keep expand as well,and here is my website on production: https://agile-coast-64468.herokuapp.com/ 
here is my home page:

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="width-r">
  <div class="this">
    <%= image_tag("wood1.jpg", class: "inside")  %>
  </div>
  <div class="this">
    <%= image_tag("wood2.jpg",class: "inside" ) %>
  </div>
  <div class="this">
    <%= image_tag("wood3.jpg", class: "inside")  %>
  </div>
  <div class="this">
    <%= image_tag("wood4.jpg", class: "inside")  %>
  </div>
  <div class="this">
    <%= image_tag("wood5.jpg", class: "inside")  %>
  </div>

</div>
<div class="jumbotron">
  <h1 align="center"> Here come the ads</h1>
</div>
```

and here is my css :

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";

.navbar {
  background-color: #fff;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
}

.width-r {
  position: relative;
}
#clip {
  position: absolute;
  clip: rect(0, 0, 581.55px, -100px);
 /* clip: shape(top, right, bottom, left); NB 'rect' is the only available     option */
}
.this {
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
  height: 581.55px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;

}
.inside {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  height: 581.55px;
  position: absolute;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.inside:hover {
  z-index:100;
  width: 110%;
}

.navbar-ma {
/* remove space between the navbar and the images below */
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.jumbotron {
  height: 220px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  z-index: 0;
}

.container-fluid {
  padding: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at the clip property for css: http://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/clip/

Comment: effet of airforce.com is not pure css but javascript + css

Comment: @Cruiser thanks it is working now with clip

Comment: @孙悟空 yes but the hover effect can be just with clip which it is in css...thanks u